# Unable to Capture screen using DirectX

Tags: visual-c++, directx

AM trying to take screenshot with DirectX in VS 2008. But always i used to get black image . Can someone point me out, whats wrong happening with my code.. my snippet code looks like this:

```
void CaptureScreen()
{
IDirect3DDevice9* pDirect3DDevice;

IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget=NULL;
IDirect3DSurface9* pDestTarget=NULL;

D3DDISPLAYMODE d3ddisplaymode;

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS PresentParams;
memset(&PresentParams, 0, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));

PresentParams.Windowed = TRUE;
PresentParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;

HWND h = ::FindWindow(0,"EIML");
IDirect3D9* direct=Direct3DCreate9(D3D9b_SDK_VERSION);
direct->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
            D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
            h,
            D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
            &PresentParams,&pDirect3DDevice);

if (pDirect3DDevice == NULL)
return;

HRESULT hr = pDirect3DDevice->GetRenderTarget(0, &pRenderTarget);

hr = direct->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,&d3ddisplaymode);

hr = pDirect3DDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(d3ddisplaymode.Width,d3ddisplaymode.Height,D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,
&pDestTarget,
NULL);

pDirect3DDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pDestTarget ) ;

hr = pDirect3DDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pRenderTarget,pDestTarget);

hr = D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile("C:\\Image1.bmp",
D3DXIFF_BMP,
pDestTarget,
NULL,
NULL);

pRenderTarget->Release();
pDestTarget->Release();

 }
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I take a screenshot:

```
IDirect3DSurface9 *offscreenSurface;
d3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &offscreenSurface);
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile( filename, D3DXIFF_BMP, offscreenSurface, 0, 0 )
```

Comment: Hi even I am trying to capture screenshot from backbuffer using directx. Can you please help me out with an MCVE or redirect me to a sample debuggable code with I can try out which uses `GetBackBuffer` to capture desktop screenshot.